# Illustrator: how to fill space between 2 shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, fill

I have drawn this in illustrator:
[image: circle + line]

It's just a circle and a hand drawn line with the paint brush tool on top of each other.

How do I go about filling in on of the two halves with a color?

Comment: Use live paint bucket tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have these 2 shapes:

[image]

You select them and grab Live Paint Bucket tool:

[image]

Next, you just choose the color and click on the area you want to paint:

[image]

[image]

To get shape of filled colors you should use expand command.

Comment: Could you explain how the new layer/shape order works after using the live paint bucket tool, if that's not too hard?

Comment: @Ruben You should expand the resulting objects in order to get regular shapes which will have the borders of the filled areas - look them at the layers panel.

Comment: Thank you, I see now. Is it common practice to expand the objects after you've filled them with the desired color?

Comment: @ruben I suggest you to read about live effects. I think that answer to your question is yes, after I fill the area, I expand the object.